# Getting Intermittent Connection Errors After Attaching a SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server, database-connection

I have a problem that I am unable to resolve.  My development team have a suite of C# unit tests that run against a unit test database.  Before each test, the database needs to be restored to its base-lined start-point.  The fastest way to achieve this is to:

1. Detach the database.
2. Overwrite the .mdf and .ldf files with base-lined backup copies.
3. Attach the database.

I perform these actions by invoking Transact SQL commands from C#.

The problem I have is that approximately 50% of the time, opening a connection to the unit test  database will fail - the exceptions are of different types - but they all seem to suggest that the database does not exist.  If I put in a 'sleep' command after the Attach statement then the database can be opened successfully every time. My interpretation of this is that there must be some sort of SQL Server background process that runs against the database to finalise bringing the database on-line.  So, directly after executing sp_attach_db, the database is not actually ready for use until after a few milliseconds.

Of course, my solution could be to execute a 'sleep' statement after every database attach but there are 800 of these tests so it is vital that the detach/restore/attach process is as fast as possible.

Does anyone have experience of this problem?  Does anyone know why the database is not immediately available to accept a connection?  Does anyone know how I can detect when the database is ready to accept a connection.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you thought about using in memory databases instead of an actual database? H2Sharp is one of those

Comment: @StigHausberg.  Moving database from SQL Server to another one simply for unit test purposes is a bonkers idea :)  What we have actually done is to store the mdf and ldf files on a ram-drive and this.

Comment: Am I understanding it right if you guys are restoring an "old/fixed" database every time you are running unit tests? "Moving database from SQL Server to another one" is what makes this totally unnecessary. This base-lined start-point you are talking about can be stored in xml files and be used by an in-memory-database as H2Sharp to run your tests against.

Comment: Yeah, think you do misunderstand.  Our unit tests will test a variety of things, and sometimes needs a database to work against.  This database is more than just static read-only data, it is a copy of our live production database.  Some of the tests will update the data in the database.  This is why I need a fast way to restore the database to it's original condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to switch off the Pooling on your connections. When Pooling is ON, your connection in the pool is broken when you forcibly close it while detaching the DB, and thus when the connection comes from connections pool - the very first batch will fail.

Simply add to your connection strings `Pooling=no`

PS: If your tests not so much complex, it can be much faster to run the test inside a transaction and simply roll it back when it finishes to clear the DB

Comment: Thanks Oleg.  As you posted that answer I was posting my own answer simultaneously. 

My interpretation of the problem was incorrect. The actual problem was that once I had attached the database then any connections in the connection pool were no longer valid.  

My solution was to clear the connection pool after attaching the database with SqlConnection.ClearAllPools().

Oleg, I'll give you credit for the answer as your solution was effectively the same thing.

BTW, agree that wrapping in a transaction is better approach but many of the tests are way too complicated to do that.