# Local site intermittently can't connect to SQL Server while SSMS can

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having the strangest problem: Everything was working fine while I was coding a new site I'm working on one night when suddenly the site could not longer connect to SQL Server. I can connect happily using SQL Server Management Studio, but the site throws the following exception.

Firewalls on this machine are completely disabled.

One issue thought is that I have SQL Server running under a local user I created. Some times when I restart the SQL Server Service to see if that resolves the problem, the service complains that the Login failed. I then re-enter the same credentials that got the service running in the first place, and then it starts up after AGAIN stating that the account has been granted login as a service rights. I have however tried using NETWORK SERVICES and LOCAL SYSTEM, both of which prompts the same exception from my site.

From time to time, however, it does work though. I'm running this on a domain connected notebook, so I'm wondering if this has something to do with it not being able to talk to the domain while I'm at home. The service account I created is however a local account.

I'm running this on IIS Express on Windows 8 Enterprise though (Just in case it's some known issue with Win8).

adding `Pooling=no` to the connection string also has no effect. [[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9413670/88496)]

Here is my connection string: `Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=NotesBoard;Integrated Security=SSPI;`
I've also used my Machine name instead on "." with the same outcome. Even tried FQDN.

> System.Web.HttpException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2147467259   Message=Unable to connect to SQL Server
>   database.   Source=System.Web   ErrorCode=-2147467259   WebEventCode=0
>   StackTrace:
>          at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.CreateMdfFile(String
>   fullFileName, String dataDir, String connectionString)
>          at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.EnsureDBFile(String
>   connectionString)
>          at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.GetConnection(String
>   connectionString, Boolean revertImpersonation)
>          at System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider.GetRolesForUser(String username)
>          at WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider.GetRolesForUser(String username)
>          at System.Web.Security.RolePrincipal.IsInRole(String role)
>          at ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.Execute() in d:\dtaylor\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\NotesBoard\NotesBoard\Views\Shared_Layout.cshtml:line
>   28
>          at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
>          at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
>          at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
>          at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__6(TextWriter
>   writer)
>          at System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer)
>          at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result)
>          at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body)
>          at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext()
>          at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17()
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter
>   filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
>   InnerException: System.Web.HttpException
>          HResult=-2147467259
>          Message=Unable to connect to SQL Server database.
>          Source=System.Web
>          ErrorCode=-2147467259
>          WebEventCode=0
>          StackTrace:
>               at System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server,
>   String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String
>   connectionString)
>               at System.Web.Management.SqlServices.SetupApplicationServices(String
>   server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String
>   connectionString, String database, String dbFileName, SqlFeatures
>   features, Boolean install)
>               at System.Web.Management.SqlServices.Install(String database, String dbFileName, String connectionString)
>               at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.CreateMdfFile(String
>   fullFileName, String dataDir, String connectionString)
>          InnerException: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>               HResult=-2146232060
>               Message=A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was
>   not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating
>   Server/Instance Specified)
>               Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
>               ErrorCode=-2146232060
>               Class=20
>               LineNumber=0
>               Number=-1
>               Server=""
>               State=0
>               StackTrace:
>                    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>                    at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>                    at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean
>   ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean
>   trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover)
>                    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean
>   withFailover)
>                    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
>   SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
>                    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer
>   timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
>                    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions)
>                    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>                    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions)
>                    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>                    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>                    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)
>                    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
>                    at System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server,
>   String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String
>   connectionString)
>               InnerException:

**Update:**
This error is more clearly defined in a new post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14357791/88496)

Answer (score 0):

> The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the
>   instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow
>   remote connections.

Looks like a network problem between the web server and the SQL server. Could be anything: firewall, DNS, ... Could also be intermittent problems with your SQL server.

Talk to your system administrator for more details. There's nothing wrong with your code.